# Word2Vec / Doc2Vec - map change of words overtime

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have text data for 10 years and I want to run a Word2Vec model on the text data each year and calculate the distances between words and I would like to compare them over time.

Are there any papers in which the Word2Vec model is compared to previous years data? Or if I have a matrix of the Word2Vec vectors are there ways to compare these matrices year-on-year or from period t to t-1?

I can compute the cosine distance of the matrix but cannot think how to compare these "scores" for each word over time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check [Diachronic Word Embeddings Reveal Statistical Laws of Semantic Change](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09096.pdf)